# SonarQube 3.7 Bug while creating new measures?

Tags: sonarqube

I created several measures on SonarQube version 3.7.

One time i created a fresh measure (let's call it Measure_A) and shared it with all users. 
Then i created more measures. To do so I simply copied Measure_A and changed its name to Measure_B. The box "Shared with all users" was checked.

When I click on the save button it seems like everything was copied and works fine. Only one thing did not work: Measure_B was not shared with all users but is private instead. So I clicked the pencil to get the menu where I could edit Measure_B's name and description and saw that the box for sharement of Measure_B was unchecked.

When I check the box now once again and saved it, Measure_B gets shared.

I tried the same several times again and got always the same result. If i copy Measure_B with a checked option "Shared with all users" the Measure_C is not shared...

Is this a known bug and maybe already solved in later versions? Or should I create a ticke on Jira/Codehaus?

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch! I just entered a JIRA ticket: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5229

Comment: so i guess it was not fixed within the latest release (4.2). Thanks for ticket creation :)